# Cannot run configure on iOS 5.1.1 due the test executable is killed (9)

Tags: code-signing, configure, ios5.1

On iOS 5.1.1 the fix for the codesigning has not been applied when jailbreaking. This means that when I launch a ./configure, it fails in its first steps as it seems that the sample programs it run actually cannot be run. There's no patch at this time to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure that your compiler actually works with no problem, all you can do now is:

- trick the ./configure that you are cross compiling by setting different --build and --host triple, such as arm-apple-darwin9 and arm-apple-darwin10;
- edit the configure and add BEFORE (eval "$ac_try") 2>&5 this line
  (eval "ldid -S ./conftest") 
  In my experience I only had to do so for the first two checks, the rest is just overkill (as the configure will detect libraries, headers and functions by checking on the compiler result, not on a run test). You should anyway notice that this may not be the only way ./configure tries to run things, and that you will have to run ldid on the final executables before using them (or they will be killed anyway) and that you won't be able to run make check.
  Credit: http://botsikas.blogspot.it/2012/06/ipad-ios-51-configure-error-connot-run.html
- wait for me to create a C compiler that run ldid automatically (of it's possible). I'm already messing with gcc to make it run on the latest devices such as iPhone 5 (which doesn't accept anymore the arm arch, but only armv7 and newer).
- Find a way to tell configure to ldid things (on this you're on your own)